# Short story about a woman who has lost her right to use science

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, science

This story would have been in a short story collection or anthology over the last few years. I think it was about a woman who would not allow medical treatment for her children due to vague non-science reasons. She was unable to provide any fact based reasoning for her beliefs and the children were treated as she "lost her right to use science."

Does anyone know the title please?

Answer (score 14):

It is:

**A taste of your own medicine** by Tony Ballantyne:

> '...
>   “I'm sorry, Ms Melham...” he began, and then more kindly. “I'm
>   sorry, Sacha, but you've crossed the threshold. I'm afraid to say,
>   you're not allowed science any more.”
>   ...'

The whole short story at this link:

http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v489/n7414/full/489170a.html

Comment: Funny thing, I read this not two days ago.  It took me 10-15 minutes to remember *where* I read the story!